# Backup unbootable Windows 7 to another partition

Tags: windows-7

Windows 7 Home Premium won't boot on my Vaio laptop even in safe mode (stuck at classpnp.sys, then it goes to a BSOD and I'm forced to restart). I tried many solutions but none of them worked.

After that I decided to boot from an USB with Ultimate Boot CD installed and ran every hardware test with positive results. Then I booted Parted Magic and it was able to mount the hard drive (even the system and recovery partition). From there I could just copy the files that I wish to keep to my external USB flash drive and make a clean Windows 7 install. The problem is that the transfer rate is painfully slow and I have a lot of pictures.

I read that Windows creates a 'windows.old' folder when doing a custom install containing the old installation Program Files and Users folders. I don't trust that since Windows can't even boot in safe mode. Are my suspicions right?

The other option is to create a new partition with Parted Magic and dump all the files there, but if I do that the Windows installation program won't create a separate System partition (around 100 mb) and I read that it's convenient to do that instead of having Windows in only one for security reasons (it didn't work for me since I already have a separate System partition).

So my question is: is it worth taking a long time transferring files to my other laptop for the sake of having Windows in two partitions? or should I just save time and use a new partition for backup? even better, is it possible to install Windows System in a separate partition when the hard drive already has an existing partition that I wish to keep?

EDIT: The VAIO recovery partition seems to be corrupted so I discarded that alternative. I also forgot to mention that I am able to run the Windows command prompt in the recovery environment but I don't know if there are any tools there that could be useful.

Comment: In the BSOD what is the stop code?  maybe you could just use **chkdsk /f c:** depending on the stop code.

Comment: Thanks for replying. That was the first thing I googled and I think I tried that but it didn't work. If I recall correctly it was 0x000000F4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I was finally able to create the backup partition AND install windows with System in a separate partition. The only thing you need is to be able to access the Windows command prompt in the recovery environment (press F8 during booting and choose Fix Startup or something like that).
The steps I took are as follows (I used multiple sources that are listed below):

1. Access said command prompt.
2. Type 'Diskpart'

   ```
   DISKPART> list disk             (output isn't shown)
   DISKPART> select disk 0         (assuming it's disk 0)
   DISKPART> list partition        (output isn't shown)
   DISKPART> select partition 1    (assuming partition 1 is the Windows **boot** partition. It should be the bigger one, not the System one)
   DISKPART> shrink QUERYMAX       (this will return the maximum number of bytes that the volume can be reduced)
   DISKPART> shrink DESIRED=204800 (which is 200 gb in mb. It is the desired space that will be used for backup)
   DISKPART> create partition primary size=204800 (this will create the backup partition)
   DISKPART> format fs=ntfs quick  (having quick added at the end of the command will do a quick format instead of a full format on the partition created previously)
   DISKPART> exit diskpart
   ```
3. Now I exited the command prompt and restarted. I had an USB flash drive with UBCD installed ([here for instructions](http://wiki.ultimatebootcd.com/?title=Tutorials:USB_Installation)). Change the BIOS boot order so the USB device option is listed first. Once in the UBCD menu choose the option called 'Parted Magic ....' and then choose the first option. This will launch the Linux-based distro Parted Magic.
4. Once there click on the File Manager icon. This will allow us to transfer files from an external flash drive and between the different partitions. In my case I transferred a lot of pictures from the Windows boot partition to the backup one I created in step 2. I also stored the most important files on another flash drive just in case something went wrong. Once we are done restart the computer and change back the BIOS so we can go to the command prompt again.
5. Again we type 'Diskpart'

   ```
   DISKPART> list disk
   DISKPART> select disk 0         (same as before)
   DISKPART> list partition
   DISKPART> select partition 2    (corrupted VAIO recovery partition in my case)
   DISKPART> delete partition override
   DISKPART> select partition 1    (Windows boot partition from which I already extracted what I wanted, should be the same as the one selected in step 2)
   DISKPART> delete partition
   DISKPART> select partition 3    (System partition, should be about 200 mb)
   DISKPART> delete partition
   DISKPART> create partition primary size=200 (new Windows System partition that will be used to install Windows again)
   DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label="System Reserved"
   DISKPART> active
   DISKPART> create partition primary size=102400 (new Windows boot partition that will be used to install Windows again)
   DISKPART> format fs=ntfs label="Windows 7"
   DISKPART> exit
   ```

   So now we should have 3 primary partitions: The backup one, the soon to be Windows System one and the soon to be Windows Boot one. The only one active is the Windows System one. You can check that by selecting it in DISKPART and typing 'detail partition'. Next we restart the computer.
6. Now insert the Windows install media into the Optical Disk Drive and restart the PC to set the first boot device as the ODD in the BIOS and install Windows 7 to the created "Windows 7" partition. You will want to do a clean install choosing the "Custom (advanced)" not the "Upgrade" option, when you are presented with this "Where do you want ... " dialog box click to choose the created "Windows 7" partition and click next; do not use the installer to format anything.

When we are able to finally access Windows we can move our backed up files to our new Windows boot partition and then delete the backup partition. We can now extend the boot partition to use the newly unallocated space. For that you can use the Disk Management tool that comes with Windows.

That's all, hope it helps.

Sources: 
 [How to Optimize an SSD / HDD When You're Ready to Reinstall the Operating System](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/91339-ssd-hdd-optimize-windows-reinstallation.html)

The other sources in comments, I'm sorry, I can't post more than 2 links with this reputation. Hopefully someone edits it.

Comment: http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/119151-system-reserved-create-using-disk-management.html

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/300415

http://hashroot.blogspot.com.ar/2012/01/using-diskpart-to-create-partition-in.html

http://www.petri.co.il/shrink-system-partition-in-windows-7.htm

Answer (score 0):

Hello so for the double partition and windows image - I to have gone through many troubleshooting on this.

1st - Well first of all could you remove the hard drive and connect it via external enclosure or hard drive a pater via usb?

if so then great and yes it is long and time consuming the best way to make sure you have a copy of the photos.

2nd - Yes when doing a custom install or regular install windows would create a windows old, not in this windows old it would have all you saved settings and directories in tact so you can go to them later and retrieve what you want and delete say windows.old folder after you copied everything to the new directory.

Only fault program here is that you will not have a clean os install, technically you will, but later you will incur this problem all over again - So i rather go option 1 or 2 once you have a backup of all files when you can then perform a clean install.

3rd - I have worked in many enterprises and they tend to have 3 separate partitions and i have tried this as personal but more like in the 2 partition and 1 hidden partition.

c: OS drive is main windows and installs only - give at least 50gb or more depending of what applications you be installing.

d: DATA drive is my data drive and of course if you run into an issue that c drive will not boot up then you can perform a clean install on the c:drive and you can be getting back to normal really quick.

Though understand if you do a clean install with out applications then you would have to link and install application all over again to your d: DATA Drive.

Now for the hidden partition as large as the C: OS Drive or less if you compress it, i have used this over and over again and love it.

I would create my c: OS drive nice and clean and organize delete any excess folders and clean up directory with CCleaner and Auslogic apps that all applications and settings are set with no login password (just easier) with password is issue if you forget but make an image when the settings and everything is set and ready could be 30-70gb, but all linked properly to your d: data drive.

```
So you would use deploy studio is free ware, or acronis truimage (cheap) or ghost (a bit more money)
```

* Deploystudio - is in linux and once you create the partition and clone it it works wonderful
* Acronis - I have used for many years and still with same old version 10 now i think it is 13-14? but this has a feature for a hidden partition so instead of creating a 3rd partition that can been seen.  Use this and it will ask to take partition space from another drive and you will not see it beside the disk management and say you OS gets corrupted you can restore in minutes than hours the exact same settings and all - I just say if you do this make the hidden partition with a password - this will prevent anyone going in destroying the image like spyware, malware.
* Ghost will do similar as acronis except you can make it external and boot from external to usb stick to place your image back to normal.

Hope this helps tell me what you have done and how it went.

Sifu - iOSGenius.com

Answer (score 0):

With all those corruptions your harddrive seems to have, this looks like you have some more trouble than just some unbootable Windows.  Perhaps there is some hardware fault.

So it is highly recommended not to play around and do trial and error, instead do a real backup first, even if it takes long.  And do not forget to verify that the backup has worked and you are not left with 30% of hidden garbage.

There are several options how to back up:

- As you did, trying to recover to some USB drive.
- Better variant (if you know how):  Buy a replacement disk.  See below.
- Or use some better backup software like Acronis True Image which works on a block level but still only saves the used parts.

Because if backups are slow there might be issues like read errors on your old harddrive.  Or worse.

### Replace your drive

This only works if you know how to replace a drive of a computer.  If not find a friend who knows.

- Buy a new replacement drive which fits into your laptop.
- Swap the drives.  So the new one is in your laptop, the old one is now outside.
- Buy some external USB case for your old drive, such that you can connect this to USB.  Put the old drive in that.
- Now re-install your laptop on the new drive.  As it is a brand new drive, you can happily experiment.  You need your recovery media for that.  If you do not have one, ask Sony.  Probably buying a new Sony is cheaper than to order the recovery media.  It's Sony, you know what you have.
- Afterwards you have a working Laptop and an external drive with all your old data.

Now you can plug your old drive into USB and read it.

But wait!  You won't be able to do so because Windows does not allow you to access the old drive.

There are several solutions to this:

Nondestructive:

- Use some good backup software like Acronis True Image (again) to transfer the data.
- Use Linux to access your data.  Perhaps put a small Linux partition on your new drive for this.

Perhaps destructive as these need to alter the drive contents:

- Either get some Windows 7 Ultimate, which is able to take ownership of the files on the drive and then set the public access mode.
- Boot your Laptop in Safe Mode (sp?  I only have the German variant, it's called "Abgesicherter Modus" there).  This mode allows you to access features, which are not available when booted normally.  (I really have no idea if this still applies, I do not have Windows 7 Home here currently.)

The problematic part of the last thing is, that you still need USB ports to operate, and it might be that they are unusable if not normally booted.

## Also recommended

Check your drive using some S.M.A.R.T. tool like [Crystal Disk Info](http://www.chip.de/downloads/CrystalDiskInfo_32778794.html).  However this needs a working Windows and normally does not work over USB.

So instead perhaps boot some `Knoppix` to use `smartctl` (smartmontools) on your drive to see it's health status.

Also for data recovery - when anything else fails like Acronis takes weeks - I usually use `gddrescue` under Linux.  It's not trivial to do so, but perhaps you have some friend who can help.  This is sure beyond any such answer here.

HTH

Comment: I don't think it is a hardware issue. Maybe I should have clarified that, but I think I corrupted the VAIO recovery partition accidentally writing MBR on it with one of the Ultimate Boot Cd tools.

Comment: perhaps http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927392/en-us `/fixboot` can help to revive that partition.

Comment: Thanks, tried that but it didn't work. I think it only fixes the Windows boot, not the VAIO recovery partition.